# UNITY no overload for method takes 1 arguments

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have a little problem. Im trying that when you shoot the enemy its lose health, so i have 2 scripts, one in the camera with the damage because its an fps, and other in the enemy with the health. The problem is that im trying to subtract the damage to the health, but that mesagge appears in the code, in target.takeDamage(damage) Thank you

My code:

CAMERA

```
    void shoot(){
    RaycastHit hit;

    //Raycast desde la camara, hacia delante, la informacion del raycast y con el rango que le demos
    if (Physics.Raycast(fpsCam.transform.position, fpsCam.transform.forward, out hit, range)) {
        Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);

        //A quien hemos impactado (), y lo llamamos target
        EnemyBase target = hit.transform.GetComponent<EnemyBase>();

        //Comprobamos si lo que hemos impactado es un enemigo
        if(target !=null){
            //Si lo es le mandamos la variable de daño
            target.TakeDamage(damage);

        }
    }

}
```

ENEMY:

```
    public void TakeDamage() {
    vidaEnemigo -= damage;
    if(vidaEnemigo <= 0f){
        Die();
    }
}

void Die(){
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `TakeDamage` function doesn't accept any parameters but you're trying to pass one in.  Give it a parameter (I'm guessing you want an `int` or a `float` here):

```
public void TakeDamage(int damage) {
    vidaEnemigo -= damage;
    if(vidaEnemigo <= 0f){
        Die();
}
```

Comment: So I have to bracket what i have to pass?   PD: It worked, thank you very much

Comment: @AxelVelasco Anything in the parenthesis following a method defines the parameters that method will accept.  [You can read more about that here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-parameters)